# Site Pages Library create custom page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, custom-list, page-layout

I am wondering if there is a way to set up a site pages webpart that creates a templated page instead of the blank one that is currently generated?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create a new page layout for that purpose. Henry Hong has a good walk through [here](http://blog.henryong.com/2010/06/08/how-to-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-page-layouts-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/). It's pretty detailed so I can't really spell it out here.

The benefit of this is it allows you to define a view for when users are adding/editing content and a view for the display by utilizing the `PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel` and setting the PageDisplayMode to `PageDisplayMode="Display"` or `PageDisplayMode="Edit"`.

I've used this to great success.

Answer (score 1):

Page layouts require a publishing site but you can create a custom ASPX page in SPD and add web part zones in the layout you want to use if you are not using a publishing site.